# Criando tabs da maneira correta no Android atualmente

Tags: android, android-fragment, actionbar

Estou tentando implementar no aplicativo que estou criando Tabs, como esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém sempre quando tento implementar me dou de cara com classes e métodos `deprecated`, como por exemplo, `TabListener`, `ActionBarActivity` e agora estou na dúvida de como vou cria-lo, não sei a maneira correta de criar e já pesquisei na internet quanto a exemplos porém esta cheio de exemplos utilizando estas classes e métodos obsoletos.

Preciso que funcione em versões antigas do SDK, quando menor a versão melhor.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: No lugar de `ActionBarActivity` use `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A melhor forma de se implementar um layout baseado em abas é usando o `TabLayout` da `design library`.

Infelizmente ela exige que você tenha o trio em seu grupo de dependências:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
```

Mas hoje em dia, se você quer fazer um app que tenha uma boa compatibilidade sem muito esforço e que agregue alguns elementos do Material Design, não tem como fugir disso.

O basico para implementar é:

## Layout básico

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## Setup na sua Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(...);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

Esse é o básico. Quando você começar a combinar o `AppBarLayout` + `CoordinatorLayout` + `Toolbar` + algum componente com `NestedScroll` você pode ter muitas variações que ficam muito boas.

Uma boa fonte para ver as possibilidades: https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32 e http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Fonte: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Comment: Obrigado, e quanto quem não utiliza o Gandle para dependências?

Comment: Hmmm, deveria usar :D mas brincadeiras a parte, não consigo ajudar tanto porque faz muito tempo que migrei pro Android Studio e uso o Gradle que não sei exatamente o processo no Eclipse e Ant. Existe esse: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html mas não consigo dizer se é tranquilo.

Comment: Eu não sei se essas tabs tem efeito de rolar, eu uso uma muito bacana que tem esse efeito, da uma conferida nesse link https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip, é muito bem explicado como usar e é bastante customizável.

Comment: @Skywalker Se quiser, monta uma resposta básica com um exemplo, pode ajudar algumas pessoas :D