# Criando menu horizontal inferior Android Studio

Tags: android

Eu quero criar um navigation bottom na minha aplicação. Eu dei uma olhada nesse que tem na documentação do Android, mas eu gostaria que os ícones não tivessem destaque de tamanho ao ser clicado, como o do YouTube.

Poderiam me auxiliar?

Comment: Tu ta procurando algo assim? https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/84048/35406) como criando *tabs*, e para fixar o [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) no rodapé, insira uma `ViewPager` antes definido a propriedade `layout_weight` como `1`. Veja como deve ficar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainTest"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Veja uma imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]